# ASP.NET 3.5 Code works on test server but not prod, system.codedom

Tags: c#, asp.net

During the night our production server now displays the following error. The exact same code works on our testserver, but not on production. It's using ASP.NET 3.5

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.codedom: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigXmlElement' to type 'System.Xml.XmlAttribute'.
>
> Line: 349

Line 349:

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
  </compiler>
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
    <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
  </compiler>
  </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

I have tried going back to older git commits when it was working, replacing Bin folder with tests' Bin-folder, and much more, but the error message remains. The servers are set up exactly the same according to my hosting company and has the same .NET-framework installed.

When setting `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />` all I see is a white page with `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosting company restored the entire folder to a previous date, and now it works. To solve it in the mean time, we redirected everything to our test server instead by the following:

```
<system.webServer>

<!--Temp to testserver-->
<rewrite>
  <rules>
  <clear />
    <rule name="Temporary test server redirect">
      <match url="^(.+)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://web.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
<system.webServer>
```

The {R:1} keeps the query parameters